# VBA Word table to Excel Paragraph and For Error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have two problems:

1. I need to copy a table in .docx that has paragraph numbering in column A. The first row the of the table is a always merged(A-C). The table can be any number of rows but follows the same format.

.docx table Ex:

```
 A   B   C
|'title...'|
|1.| T | F |
|2.| F | T |
|3.| T | T |
```

I know this code looks at (2, 1) but it does not return that table numbering '1.'. It just returns (2, 1) as a blank cell.
Ideally it would return the values of '1' (Without the period).

2. When I run the full code it passes through to 'Next iCol' the first time and then errors at 'Cells(resultRow, iCol)...' with: "The Requested member of the collection does not exist". I am thinking it has something to do with the first row being merged so Cell(1,2) does not exist but I am not sure of the solution.

CODE IN QUESTION:

```
ElseIf .Found = True Then
        For iRow = 1 To wrdDoc.Tables(3).Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To wrdDoc.Tables(3).Columns.Count
            Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(wrdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
        Next iCol
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        Next iRow
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
    End If
```

The final results in excel should match the .docx table without the column A period. If is easier the 'title' can just be placed in A1 with the rest of the table to follow.

```
 A   B   C
|'title..'|
|1| T | F |
|2| F | T |
|3| T | T |

OR

 A    B   C
|tle|   |   | 
|1  | T | F |
|2  | F | T |
|3  | T | T |
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Dim i as long
  With wrdDoc.Tables(3).Range
    For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
      If .Cells(i).RowIndex > iRow Then resultRow = resultRow + 1
      iRow = .Cells(i).RowIndex: iCol = .Cells(i).ColumnIndex
        ActiveSheet.Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cells(i).Range.Text)
    Next
  End With
```

Note the inclusion of a worksheet reference in the code - you may need to define that differently.

Comment: Thank you! This solves problem 2. But column A is still always blank after returning the text from Row 1 (A2, A3, A4).

Comment: I have not figured out a solution for getting column A to return the paragraph numbering found in the table. I was thinking I could just return 'i' value in (resultRow, 1) but it get overwritten by the Cells(resultRow, iCol). One thing I left out and can probably solution my self depending on what the fix is - While Row 1 is always a merged cell, Row 2 also contains title cells and so the numbering never starts until Row3. Meaning for all Cells(3,1) is always "1." and Cells(4,1) is "2." and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If the first cell in each row is formatted as "numbered list" then you can read the value like this:

```vb
Dim r As Long
With wrdDoc.Tables(3)
    For r=2 to .Rows.Count
        Debug.Print .Cell(r, 1).Range.ListFormat.ListValue
    Next r
End with
```

Or use `ListFormat.ListString` if the list uses (eg) A, B, C, ...

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted works fine for me - The first output cell in Excel contains the first cell's text from the Word table. If that cell contains automatic numbering, though, the automatic number is not output. That is consistent with your own code.

The problem with trying to capture content that is included with automatic numbering is that such numbering is usually followed by a tab, which Excel will at best interpret as a column separator. For example:

```
wrdDoc.Tables(3).Range.Copy
xlWkSht.Cells(resultRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
resultRow = resultRow + wrdDoc.Tables(1).Range.Rows.Count
```